# Can we have the mapping for OleDB Source to Excel Destination at runtime rather than at design time?

Tags: ssis

I am trying to create a SSIS package that will export csv data to an excel file. This package will be called up from C# giving the csv file as input to the package. I am quite new to SSIS and I've been able to produce the expected result with same headers.

I went with the following approach -

1. Script task - created scripts from the csv headers to create temp table, bulk insert, excel table scripts.
2. Execute SQL Task - created a temp table in database
3. Execute SQL Task - Bulk insert csv data into table
4. Execute SQL Task - Create Excel file
5. Data Flow Task - OleDB Source to Excel Destination
6. Execute SQL Task - Drop the temp table created

The challenge I am facing is that my csv may have different headers (both text and number of headers may be different). And I want a single package to serve this purpose.

With the headers being different, the mapping between OleDB Souce to Excel Destination in step 5 above is not working for dynamic headers and is giving unexpected results in the excel output. Is there any way these mappings can be decided at runtime and not at design time.

Comment: You will need to write a custom destination.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please indicate some reference where to start with, which method of shall be overriden to map the columns dynamically at runtime?

Comment: There's quite a lot on SO about writing to Excel using OLEDB and C#. It's quite easy for the most part. The only thing is that it is quite slow. That's fine for small data sets but if you want to output large amounts of data consider outputting the data to CSV instead.

Comment: I would be having quite large datasets. This package is generating xls and xlsx outputs for me. Xls files can only hold 65000 odd rows in a single sheet and that is the main reason I am using an SSIS package here. This package splits the results in different sheets when the records are more than the threshold in xls format. Its the user who chooses the output format and we want to continue providing xls file support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you **can** specify the columns or column mappings of a Data Flow at SSIS runtime. You could build the SSIS package on-the-fly, which would allow your C# code to create the column mappings, but the mappings have to be created before the package can run. See [Building Packages Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345167.aspx) in MSDN for details.

On the other hand, if all you're trying to do is convert a CSV file into an Excel spreadsheet, it would seem logical to me to use the [Workbook.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the Office object model.

Comment: Hi Edmund, thanks for the reply. I cannot use the Workbook.SaveAs() due to some requirements needed.
Is it possible to create the Data Flow Task and create the mappings needed in the SSIS package programmatically in a Script Task? I think then I would be able to do the mappings in the script as I would be having the csv file before the package starts executing but not before that.